# Selenium webdriver: element.clear() not clearing the textbox values sometimes

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to clear a text box value which has default data as current time or current date. What I usually do is use element.clear() to clear the textbox and later use element.sendkeys() to enter my data. But now what happens is that in a single iteration, some times the above logic works and the data given is saved. But in some cases the text box value is not cleared and the date or time got saved as the default one. It happens randomly. 
The webdriver version is 2.46.0

Comment: give some time to clear the text box.

Comment: you can use tread sleep after clear the text box and before send key.

Comment: Have tried the both way. But works in one iteration, but in next the problem arises again

Answer (score 0):

Try using a nice try\catch or if statement to verify the element.text attribute is blank before you sendkeys(). That should ensure the data is cleared before continuing and adding in new text.